# how to implement GO TO page number feature in DisplayTag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, displaytag

I am using the display tag in JSTL for implementing the Pagination in the JSP pages.
I am looking for the following features 
[image]

When I click on NEXT  / PREV Links, its going to the next pages,
ie if I am in Page 2, its going to Page 3, But I am expecting if I click on Next, the page numbers should change to 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18..(next set of Pages)

is that possible to implement in the display tag the above feature???

2) Suppose if I have 50 total pages, that are displaying, is that possible for me to have a feature where users can enter the Page Number and click go, then user should be able to navigate to that given page.

Complete pagination code what I have is

```
<display:table name="webview" id="webviewit" class="grlist" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" pagesize="10" requestURI="">
    <display:column property="size" title="Size" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="dateTime" title="Date" sortable="true" class="tableBg"/>
    <display:column property="filename" title="File/Directory" sortable="true" />       
</display:table>
```

Comment: off course it is possible, now, what did you try? are you using any particular framework?

Comment: I am not using any framework, its jsut a plain JSP

Answer (score 1):

The very easiest way, you can modify the `TableTag.java` which is in the display-tag jar file. In this file modify the `initParameters()` method. Inside the method
place the below 4 line code.
After this line which is in `initParameters()` method.

```
this.pageNumber = (pageNumberParameter == null) ? 1 : pageNumberParameter.intValue();
```

Place the below code

```
if((request.getParameter("pageno") != null) && (request.getParameter("pageno") != ""))
{
     this.pageNumber=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pageno"))
}
```

And use a `TextBox` with the name pageno in your `DisplayTag` page. Also include the name in your `DisplayTag` property `excludedparam`.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" with the displaytag is that it tries to do *in memory* pagination. It means that you are going to store everything in the session. Using displaytag you could do something called **partial list support**. In that case you have to send a list of `PaginatedList` as the doc says:

*If the object passed to the displaytag as a list is in fact an instance of org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList (and not a collection), displaytag will assume that the list is externally sorted and paginated. Implementing this interface is trivial, and an adapter over existing classes can easily be written. See the org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList javadocs for more details.*

you will have urls like this

http://foo.bar.com/context/requestUri?sort=name&dir=asc&page=5&originalParameters=originalValues

for further details take a look at the doc:

http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html

If you don't want to use this technique you could use another alternative with more freedom. You could fetch directly what you want from the db. Take a look at this page (it is not exactly as you wanted it), it will give a basic idea of how to do it: `http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/` . The main points are:

1. Having  parameter that tells you in which page you are:

   if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
     page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
2. With that parameter you fetch the proper data

   List list = dao.viewAllEmployees((page-1)*recordsPerPage,
                                recordsPerPage);
   int noOfRecords = dao.getNoOfRecords();
   int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
   request.setAttribute("employeeList", list);
   request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
   request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
3. Then, in your jsp you controls your links for navigation
   to the previous page

   ```
   <c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
       <td><a href="employee.do?page=${currentPage - 1}">Previous</a></td>
   </c:if>
   ```

the rendering of the table is exactly as you had it before: 
   `<display:table ...> </display:table>`

and the 'next one' link

```
    <c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
        <td><a href="employee.do?page=${currentPage + 1}">Next</a></td>
    </c:if>
```